# props of the component is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a component(Chat) which will render another component(Conversation) after it gets some data from database and pass it as props

```
const Chat = () => {
  const [conversation, setConversation] = useState([]);
  const { name, id } = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.user; // this will get the user info from redux store
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getConversations = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${getConversationRoute}/${id}`, {
          withCredentials: true,
          credentials: "include",
        });
        setConversation(res.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getConversations();
  }, [id]);
  // const  = userState.name ? "true" : "false";
  return (
    <div className="chatPage">
      <div className="chatMenu">
        <input
          placeholder="search for a friend!"
          className="chatMenuInput"
        ></input>
        {conversation.map((conversation) => (
          <Conversation members={conversation}></Conversation>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="chatBox">
        <div className="chatBoxTop">
          <Message own={true}></Message>
        </div>
        <div className="chatBoxBottom">
          <textarea
            placeholder="say hello!"
            className="chatMessageInput"
          ></textarea>
          <button className="chatSubmitButton">send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="chatOnlineWrapper">
        <ChatOnline></ChatOnline>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

i'm aware that the function is async and the conversation component might get mounted before the data is fetched , but when the data is recieved the state in chat component will change which in turn will rerender the conversation and repass the children , but it doesn't do that
i inspected the code and i have a weird behavior

```
conversation did mount Conversation.js:6
Object {  }
Conversation.js:9
conversation did mount Conversation.js:6
Object { members: {…} }
Conversation.js:9
conversation did mount Conversation.js:6
Object { members: {…} }
Conversation.js:9
conversation did mount Conversation.js:6
Object {  }
```

which means that the props is sent and emptied again , how is that possible?

the conversation component

```
const Conversation = (props) => {
  console.log("conversation did mount");
  const { name, id } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className="conversation">
      <img
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/40"
        alt="userPhoto"
        className="conversationImage"
      ></img>
      <span className="conversationName">{name}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Conversation;
```

im following this tutorial and it works fine with him , but doesn't work with me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HggSXt1Hzfk&t=3146s

Comment: There must be more to the console output than you've shown. Your `Chat` component **definitely** calls `Conversation` with `members={[]}` on the very first render, but that isn't shown in your output. The subsequent empty props objects could be explained by `res.data` being `undefined` in `setConversation(res.data)`. A prop with the value `undefined` is not included (at all) on the props object.

Comment: Without knowing what's actually in the data everything will be conjecture. The log in `Conversation` is a bit misleading; that's not a mount, but a render. Tangential, but things would be clearer if a collection of conversations was called `conversations` and the param to `map` was a single `conversation`.

Comment: So you'll need to debug why `res.data` is `undefined` as of `setConversation(res.data)` sometimes. That falls outside the scope of the code you've shown.

Comment: what i have shown is the logs once the chat is mounted , the very first render of conversation is shown in the logs object {} conversation.js:9 , and i logged res.data and it have the information i need

Comment: @esraa - If the first first log shows that, then there is some **other** code using `Conversation`. The code in the question will not show that, it *will* start with `members: []`. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (Please see the link for details.)

Comment: Also worth noting that your `useState` initializes `conversation` with `[]`, but when `members` is present on the props, it's a non-array object. So that's something else to look at.

Comment: YES , YOU ARE RIGHT! , i used Conversation inside ChatOnline component and didn't pass it a prop so it make it null , right?? i comented it out and the project is now working , thank you so much!

Comment: Wow, I'm glad that helpd!! Happy coding! :-) *(It didn't make it `null`, it just didn't pass any props at all, so props was an empty object.)*

Answer (score -1):

This can be a case that when you are calling the API the data takes some time to load. So, when the conversation component gets loaded before the data get loaded from API. You can either use a loader in chat when the conversation is not loaded from API or use dependency of the conversation in useEffect in conversation component so that when the data get changed the conversation gets rerendered. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: The initial state of `conversation` is an empty array so no `<Conversation>` components will be rendered on initial render. Something else is happening.